# Нужно чтобы при выборе радиокнопки и нажатию кнопки вызывалась соответствующая функция

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
def onOpen():
    if var.get()==0:
        but.bind('<Button-1>',discr)
    elif var.get()==1:
        but.bind('<Button-1>',FunCompute)


root=Tk()
var=IntVar(root)

rad0 = Radiobutton(root,text="Discr", variable=var,value=0)
rad1 = Radiobutton(root,text="FunCompute", variable=var,value=1)
but=Button(root,text='open',command=onOpen)
but.pack()
rad0.pack()
rad1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто вызывайте нужную функцию напрямую внутри обработчика:

```
def onOpen():
    if var.get()==0:
        discr()
    elif var.get()==1:
        FunCompute()
```